# How to draw an allipse (oval) on a Highchart graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ellipse, rect, oval

I have two series and their intersection point. I want to have an oval (ellipse) on a chart with center in intersection. Oval radiuses should be set in terms of axis units to show area of interest for each axis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [
      // first series
      {
        name: 'IPR',
        data: [[0, 30.5],[18.5, 25.4],[30, 19.4],[38, 9.7],[42, 0.02]]
      }, 
      // second series
      {
        name: 'VLP', 
        data: [[2, 0.5],[7, 1],[14, 6],[21, 22],[29, 29.6],[40, 30.3],[50, 27.2]]
      }, 
      // intersection
      {
        name: 'Operating point',
        data: [
          [22.42, 23.35]
        ]
      }
    ],
})
```

How can I programmatically draw an oval in intersection and make zoom work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Renderer.createElement` to create other SVG elements in Highcharts:

```
    this.renderer.createElement('ellipse').attr({
      cx: 60,
      cy: 60,
      rx: 50,
      ry: 25,
      'stroke-width': 2,
      stroke: 'red',
      fill: 'yellow',
      zIndex: 3
    }).add();
```

For translating to axis units use `toPixels` as @Anton Rybalko suggested.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ds6aj5yp/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/ellipse
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: This is better than using rect

Answer (score 3):

The SVG Renderer is not really a great answer.

The polygon feature should be used (with many points, which you can generate offline in a backend, or analytically in the front end):

```
series: [{
        name: 'Target',
        type: 'polygon',
        data: [[153, 42], [149, 46], [149, 55], [152, 60], [159, 70], [170, 77], [180, 70],
            [180, 60], [173, 52], [166, 45]],
        color: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.5).get(),
        enableMouseTracking: false

    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polygon/

Comment: Wow, useful feature! Thanks for the answer, but I need to show the area around the point of interest with specific radius. So I need to calculate several points for polygon to draw an ellipse. I don't want to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

To draw a circle, line etc [SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) can be used. But there is no method to draw an ellipse. However [rect()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect) with rounded corners can be used.

Following code can be used to draw an ellipse in point (100, 200) px, horizontal radius 20 px and vertical radius 10 px:

```
chart.renderer.rect(100, 100, 20, 10, '50%')
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke': 'green',
        'fill': 'yellow',
        zIndex: 0
    })
    .add();
```

To specify x, y and radiuses in terms of axis untits [Axis.toPixels()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels) can be used. If we need to convert point (22.42, 23.35) to pixels it can be done like:

```
var x = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(22.42),
    y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(23.35)
```

So function to draw an ellipse would be:

```
var drawEllipse = function(chart, x, y, xr, yr) {
  var x1 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x-xr)
  var x2 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x+xr)
  var y1 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y-yr)
  var y2 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y+yr)
  $('.' + rectClass).remove()
  chart.renderer.rect(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2, '50%')
    .attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke': 'green',
        'fill': 'yellow',
        'zIndex': 0
    })
    .add();
};
```

Finnaly [redraw](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.redraw) event can be used to redraw ellipse after zoom:

```
$(function() {
  var drawEllipse = function(chart, x, y, xr, yr) {
    // get pixel coordinates of rect
    var x1 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x-xr)
    var x2 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x+xr)
    var y1 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y-yr)
    var y2 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y+yr)
    // remove previous ellipse
    var rectClass = 'operating-point-ellipse'
    $('.' + rectClass).remove()
    // draw ellipse using rect()
    chart.renderer.rect(x1, y2, x2 - x1, y1 - y2, '50%')
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        'stroke': 'green',
        'fill': 'green',
        'fill-opacity': 0.2,
        'zIndex': 0
      })
      .addClass(rectClass)
      .add();
  };

  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
        redraw: function() {
          drawEllipse(this, 22.42, 23.35, 6, 3);
        },
        load: function() {
          drawEllipse(this, 22.42, 23.35, 6, 3);
        }
      }
    },
    //...
  });
});
```

See full code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arybalko/rcct2r0b/